# Re-align the [alignment] tag

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request

Usage of the undefined [alignment](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/alignment) tag is split between referring to visual appearance of content and partitioning disk drives.  The usage should be split between two new specific tags.  I'll toss out two suggestions: [visual-alignment](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/visual-alignment) and [partition-alignment](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/partition-alignment).  Better suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: At 1st I was leaning more towards burning [alignment] like its a witch and we're in Salem, but after reading through some of the 62 questions, it does appear people find it to be a useful task-tag, so now I quite like it. You solution of seperating its contents into 2 new tags, [visual-alignment] and [partition-alignment] make perfect sense to me.